# How to install TeX Live only with selected package before installation begins?

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

Because my computer uses 64GB SSD hard drive, I have very limited space.

[image]

As you can see, my drive is almost full. Besides installing TeXLive, I also have to install Visual Studio addons, TeXnicCenter, ImageMagic, Adobe Acrobat, GhostScript, etc.

I want to use LaTeX just for combining some PDF files using

- `pdfpages` package
- `book` or `article` document class
- `graphicx` package
- `pgffor` package

Is it possible to install TeX Live only with these items selected before the installation begins? (In my previous installation, I forgot whether or not there is such as feature. Sorry for this simple question.)

Comment: Are you just combining individual pages? It might be simpler just to use ghostscript

Comment: @repurposer: but I need a table of contents too.

Comment: I also need to add some notes in the combined pdf, etc, etc. So using LaTeX is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation:

> TeX Live features a manual installation with a lot of possible customizations. You can get the network installer at tug.org. This installer allows you to select precisely the packages you want to install. As a result, you may have everything you need for less than 100 MB. TeX Live is then managed through its own package manager, tlmgr. It will let you configure the distributions, install or remove extra packages and so on.